# Character Motion in BGE: Hold Two keys at the same time

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I am making an FPS in BGE and I am confused on something.  Before I upgraded to Blender 2.74 it make it so if you would hold the W and A key at the same time then the character would move both along the x and y axis at the same time to make the character go diagonally.  Now it will not move at both axis at the same time, but whatever is pressed last.  The problem is that you can't move left and go forward at the same time, or right and forward ect.  I am probably making some simple mistake.  I have an example below. [image]Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

### Solution

All you literally need to do to fix this is Click this button. (on all of your Motion Actuators)

[image]

### Reason

When the ***Ad*** button is *not* clicked, each Actuator is setting the location, and is is overriding any other Actuators activated previously, regardless of whether or not they are still running. Enabling the ***Ad*** button makes each Actuator add to the change in location, enabling multiple Actuators to be executing at the same time.